# pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying to insert data from a python dictionary to mySql DB. but I don't understand what is wrong with my sql query.

I am Getting this error:

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''DiedIn' ('name', 'city') VALUES
>   ('\'Ethel_Merman\'', '\'New_York_City\\n\'')' at line 1")

this is my code:

```
import pymysql.cursors

wasBornIn = {}
with open("wasBornIn.txt") as f:
for line in f:
   (key, val) = line.split(':')
   wasBornIn[key] = val

diedIn = {}
with open("diedIn.txt") as f:
for line in f:
   (key, val) = line.split(':')
   diedIn[key] = val

 isLocatedIn = {}
 with open("isLocatedIn.txt") as f:
for line in f:
   (key, val) = line.split(':')
   isLocatedIn[key] = val

connection = pymysql.connect(host='********', user='******', password='******', db='*******',
                         charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
try:
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
# Create a new record
    sql = "DROP TABLE DiedIn"
    cursor.execute(sql)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
# Create a new record
    sql = "DROP TABLE isLocatedIn"
    cursor.execute(sql)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
# Create a new record
    sql = "DROP TABLE BornIn"
    cursor.execute(sql)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "CREATE TABLE `DiedIn`(`name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, `city` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, " \
         "PRIMARY KEY(`name`)) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8" \
          " COLLATE = utf8_bin;"
    cursor.execute(sql)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "CREATE TABLE `isLocatedIn`(`name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, `location` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, " \
         "PRIMARY KEY(`name`)) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8" \
          " COLLATE = utf8_bin;"
    cursor.execute(sql)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "CREATE TABLE `BornIn`(`name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, `city` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, " \
         "PRIMARY KEY(`name`)) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8" \
          " COLLATE = utf8_bin;"
    cursor.execute(sql)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    for key, value in diedIn.iteritems():
        strKey = repr(key)
        strValue = repr(value)
        sql = "INSERT INTO 'DiedIn' ('name', 'city') VALUES (%s, %s);"
        cursor.execute(sql, (strKey, strValue))
# connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
# your changes.
connection.commit()
finally:
connection.close()
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: ('\'Ethel_Merman\'', '\'New_York_City\\n\'')' look at the characters those are creating the problem. escape them

Answer (score -1):

try:

`sql = "INSERT INTO 'DiedIn' (name, city) VALUES ('%s', '%s');"`